# LinkedIN Encounter error: Your application has not been authorized for the scope "r_basicprofile"

Tags: api, oauth, linkedin-api

I was able to connect to the LinkedIn API for about two months and everything was correct. Was wondering if there has been any change to the API lately to block my app like so?

The app was in development stage and mostly 5 hits a day against their API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not you, it's LinkedIn. See others complaining about the same issue: https://twitter.com/search?q=linkedin%20oauth